# Finding $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(\frac\pi{\sqrt{n^2+k}})$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, summation, riemann-sum

Find $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(\frac\pi{\sqrt{n^2+k}})$$

I think this has to be evaluated with riemann sums. I tried using $\sin x\approx x$ as n is big, but that got me to $\int_0^1 (1+1/x)^{-1/2}$ but that gives me the wrong answer. Any suggestions?

EDIT: I would like to see a solution with Riemann sums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this can be done without Riemann sums.

You may use the fact that, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\sin\left(\frac\pi{\sqrt{n^2+k}}\right) =\frac\pi{\sqrt{n^2+k}}+O\left(\frac\pi{(n^2+k)^{3/2}}\right)
$$ to get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\sin\left(\frac\pi{\sqrt{n^2+k}}\right) =\sum_{k=1}^n\frac\pi{\sqrt{n^2+k}}+\sum_{k=1}^nO\left(\frac\pi{(n^2+k)^{3/2}}\right).
$$ On the one hand, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\frac{\pi\: n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\leq \sum_{k=1}^n\frac\pi{\sqrt{n^2+k}}\leq\frac{\pi\: n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}
$$ giving,  as $n \to \infty$,

> $$
> \sum_{k=1}^n\frac\pi{\sqrt{n^2+k}} \to \pi.
> $$

On the other hand, there exists $C\geq 0$ such that, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\frac{C\pi\: n}{(n^2+n)^{3/2}}\leq \sum_{k=1}^nO\left(\frac\pi{(n^2+k)^{3/2}}\right)\leq\frac{C\pi\: n}{(n^2+1)^{3/2}}
$$ giving,  as $n \to \infty$,

> $$
> \sum_{k=1}^nO\left(\frac\pi{(n^2+k)^{3/2}}\right) \to 0.
> $$

Finally,

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \sin\left(\frac\pi{\sqrt{n^2+k}}\right)= \pi.$$

Answer (score 3):

Use the inequality 
$$x - \frac{1}{6}x^3 \leq \sin x \leq x, \quad x \in [0, \pi/2).$$
For sufficiently large $n$, the summand satisfies:
$$\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{n^2 + k}} - \frac{1}{6}\frac{\pi^3}{(n^2 + k)^{3/2}} \leq \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{n^2 + k}}\right) \leq \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{n^2 + k}} \tag{1}.$$
For $k \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$, the right side bound in $(1)$ is bounded above by $\frac{\pi}{n}$, while the left side bound in $(1)$ is bounded below by
$$\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{n^2 + n}} - \frac{1}{6}\frac{\pi^3}{n^3}.$$
It thus follows that
$$\frac{n\pi}{\sqrt{n^2 + n}} - \frac{1}{6}\frac{\pi^3}{n^2} \leq \sum_{k = 1}^n\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{n^2 + k}}\right) \leq \pi.$$
By the squeeze principle, we conclude that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^n\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{n^2 + k}}\right) = \pi.$$